# Why do I keep seeing double property declarations?

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do I need to have both iVar and a property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991863/when-do-i-need-to-have-both-ivar-and-a-property)

I keep seeing the following in objective-C code.

```
@interface Contact : RKObject {  
    NSNumber* _identifier;  
    NSString* _name;  
    NSString* _company;  
}  

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* identifier;  
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* name;  
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* company;
```

Why is the bit inside of the block with the interface also required? Is that instead of using @synthesize?

Answer (score 3):

The block inside the `@interface` are the `ivars` for your class, while the 3 elements below it are the `properties`, that is accessors (getters and setters) for your ivars.

> You typically access an object’s **properties** (in the sense of its
>   attributes and relationships) through a pair of accessor
>   (**getter/setter**) methods. By using accessor methods, you adhere to the
>   principle of encapsulation. You can exercise tight
>   control of the behavior of the getter/setter pair and the underlying
>   state management while clients of the API remain insulated from the
>   implementation changes.
>
> Although using accessor methods therefore has significant advantages,
>   writing accessor methods is a tedious process. Moreover, aspects of
>   the property that may be important to consumers of the API are left
>   obscured—such as whether the accessor methods are thread-safe or
>   whether new values are copied when set.
>
> ***Declared properties*** address these issues by providing the following
>   features:
>
> - The property declaration provides a clear, explicit specification of how the accessor methods behave.
> - The compiler can synthesize accessor methods for you, according to the specification you provide in the declaration.
> - Properties are represented syntactically as identifiers and are scoped, so the compiler can detect use of undeclared properties.

**Reference :** https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1

Answer (score 2):

Extending Dr. kameleon's answer, the iVars are unnecessary in this case, as they can be declared explicitly at the @synthesize line.  For instance, `@synthesize name = _name` would be the same as declaring the iVar in the .h (note that the property is required for this syntax).  Neither one is more OK than the other, one is just more efficient coding.

Comment: This didn't use to be available until 64-bit applications were an option, correct?  Or am I mixing up my events?

Comment: @sudo, I believe that is correct.  Snow leopard x64 and iOS 3.x were the first time we were allowed to leave iVars undeclared in the .h.

Comment: It's not directly connected to 64-bit apps, but to the new, "modern" Objective-C runtime, with [non-fragile ivars](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/dynamic-ivars-solving-fragile-base.html) (and see [Greg Parker's post](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/01/27/objc_explain_Non-fragile_ivars.html)) -- there's no causal relationship, they were just introduced at the same time. @sudo